# Помигите распарсить json

Tags: golang, golang-struct

{"response":{"items":[{"id":13,"date":1527619106,"owner_id":489397284,"from_id":489397284,"post_type":"post","text":"И вновь дискретка ИУ9 ","attachments":[{"type":"photo","photo":{"id":456239052,"album_id":253019174,"owner_id":489397284,"photo_75":"https://pp.userapi.com/c844617/v844617900/65a2a/ouMnU69bedw.jpg","photo_130":"https://pp.userapi.com/c844617/v844617900/65a2b/FZo6n1roNj4.jpg","photo_604":"https://pp.userapi.com/c844617/v844617900/65a2c/VwLy9GxNJPY.jpg","width":506,"height":456,"text":"Дискретная математика Golang ИУ9","date":1527619038,"access_key":"8771a4a3229d363fe2"}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"groups_can_post":true,"can_post":0},"likes":{"count":1,"user_likes":0,"can_like":1,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":0,"user_reposted":0}},{"id":794,"date":1527618600,"owner_id":-152584921,"from_id":-152584921,"post_type":"post","text":"СПЕЦИАЛИСТЫ MALWAREBYTES ОБНАРУЖИЛИ НОВЫЙ ВИРУС-МАЙНЕР ДЛЯ MAC\n \nСогласно статье в блоге компании Malwarebytes, занимающейся кибербезопасностью, в сети появился новый вирус, заражающий компьютеры Mac вредоносным ПО для майнинга криптовалюты Monero (XMR). \n \nДиректор Malwarebytes по Mac и мобильным устройствам Томас Рид рассказал, что на компьютерах, ставших жертвами этого вируса, выполняется безвредный процесс «mshelper», который использует значительную часть вычислительной мощности процессора для майнинга криптовалюты в пользу неизвестного злоумышленника. \n \nОднако для самих компьютеров это заражение «не очень опасно». \n«Из сообщений на форумах Apple стало известно о том, что пользователи жалуются на вредоносный процесс «mshelper», который начинает пожирать вычислительные ресурсы процессора. Программа эта не очень сложная и ее легко удалить. После того, как мы изучили поведение данного вируса, нам удалось обнаружить еще несколько подозрительных процессов, создававших копии вредоносной программы». \n \nВирус состоит из трех частей: дроппера (программы-носителя, которая устанавливает вредоносное ПО), средства запуска и самого майнера, созданного на базе XMRig с открытым кодом. \n \nСпециалистам Malwarebytes пока не удалось обнаружить программу дроппера, но как показывает анализ прошлых случаев - это были поддельные установщики Adobe Flash Player и другие установочные программы. \n \nИзвестно, что средством запуска является программа «pplauncher», которую устанавливает майнер, написанная на языке Golang, который является довольно странным выбором, так как по мнению Рида, «использование этого языка для столь простой задачи - признак того, что человек сделавший это, мало знаком с Mac». \n \nРид пришел к выводу, что хотя этот майнер доставляет некоторые неудобства удалить его очень просто. Также он отметил: «В последнее время наблюдается повышенная активность вирусов-майнеров как для Mac, так и для Windows. И все же, хотя я не считаю такое ПО чем-то хорошим, я бы предпочел заразиться майнером, чем какой-либо другой вредоносной программой». \n\n#minebe #облачныймайнинг #майнинг #криптовалюта #криптоинвестиции #криптоновости","marked_as_ads":0,"attachments":[{"type":"photo","photo":{"id":456239438,"album_id":-7,"owner_id":-152584921,"user_id":100,"photo_75":"https://pp.userapi.com/c846017/v846017482/6467e/bwe5GDE6drk.jpg","photo_130":"https://pp.userapi.com/c846017/v846017482/6467f/Ysk4jpdfx-U.jpg","photo_604":"https://pp.userapi.com/c846017/v846017482/64680/nPV31_tD6Lo.jpg","photo_807":"https://pp.userapi.com/c846017/v846017482/64681/hOtmqCrZuzs.jpg","photo_1280":"https://pp.userapi.com/c846017/v846017482/64682/0oYt9ETvIs8.jpg","width":900,"height":500,"text":"","date":1527607946,"post_id":794,"access_key":"2bb622f969436f1bb9"}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":0,"user_likes":0,"can_like":1,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":0,"user_reposted":0}}],"count":1000,"total_count":4093,"next_from":"2/-152584921_794"}}

выше представлен json ответ от api. 
из него мне нужно вытянуть всего две вещи, это owner_id и id.

имеется следущий код:

```
body:= &Body{}
err = json.Unmarshal(byt,body)
if err != nil{
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println("Error when unmarsh json \n")
}
```

где byt это ответ от сервера

структура body выглядит так:

```
type Body struct {
Response []Response `json:"response"`
```

}

```
type Response struct {
Items string `json:"items"`
```

}

```
type Items struct {
    Post_id string `json:"id"`
    Owner_id string `json:"owner_id"`
    From_id   string `json:"from_id"`
}
```

получаю ошибку: unexpected end of JSON input.

Не могли бы вы мне помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поля структуры должны называться так же, как поля в json (только с большой буквы). Плюс поле `Response` это не список, а `Items` как раз список

```
type Response struct {
    Response Resp
}

type Resp struct {
    Items []Item
}

type Item struct {
    ID int
    Owner_id int
    From_id int
}

func main() {
    resp := Response{}
    json_b := []byte(`{     "response": {   "items": [{ "id": 13,   "date": 1527619106, "owner_id": 489397284,  "from_id": 489397284}]} }`)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(json_b, &resp); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(resp.Response.Items[0].ID)
        fmt.Println(resp.Response.Items[0].Owner_id)
        fmt.Println(resp.Response.Items[0].From_id)
    }
}
```